# rails js.erb if else statement doesn't get executed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

This JS.erb doesn't get executed. What did I miss? (There is something about the ruby if else statement as it was running perfectly before I inserted that.)

On the top of that if there is a more elegant solution pls let me know. I divided the @task into 2 partials as on the users/show page and on tasks/index,outgoing tasks,completed tasks, the displayed fields are different. Other solution I see would be putting a bunch of is/else statement in the views/forms/js.erb-s.

UPDATE below code.

```
var ready = function () {
    $("#newtask").modal('hide');
    $(".task_name_company").val('');
    $(".contentarea").val('');
    $(".task_deadline").val('');

    <% if params[:action] == "show" && params[:controller] == "users" %>
        $(".newtaskinsert").prepend('<%= j render (:partial => "tasks/task_between") %>');
    <% else %>
        $(".newtaskinsert").prepend('<%= j render @task %>');
    <% end %>

    $("#task_<%= @task.id %>").hide().fadeIn(1000);

    //26= pagination(12)*every task has 2 tr(2)+ extra task that must be hidden(2)=12*2+2
    var n = $('tr').length;
    if (n > 26) {
        $("tr").slice((-2*(n-26)/2)-1).fadeOut(500);
    };
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

UPDATE:

With taking out the parantheses from :partial it's running, but still not what I want. How can I distinguish users/2 from users/2/tasks or from users/2/outgoing_tasks w/ this if else statement?

Comment: [`action_name`](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/ActionController/Base:action_name) and [`controller_name`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Metal/controller_name/class)

Comment: Rich, first problem solved. I had to take out the parantheses from the :partial. I have another one though. How can I distinguish /users/2 from /users/2/tasks or from /users/2/outgoing tasks w/ the if else statement?